# Are pseudo random number generators less likely to repeat?

Tags: random

So they say if you flip a coin 50 times and get heads all 50 times, you're still 50/50 the next flip and 1/4 for the next two.  Do you think/know if this same principle applies to computer pseudo-random number generators?  I theorize they're less likely to repeat the same number for long stretches.

I ran this a few times and the results are believable, but I'm wondering how many times I'd have to run it to get an anomaly output.

```
def genString(iterations):
   mystring = ''
   for _ in range(iterations):
       mystring += str(random.randint(0,9))
   return mystring


def repeatMax(mystring):
    tempchar = ''
    max = 0
    for char in mystring:
            if char == tempchar:
                    count += 1
                    if count > max:
                            max = count
            else:
                count = 0
            tempchar = char
    return max


for _ in range(10):
    stringer = genString()
    print repeatMax(stringer)
```

I got all 7's and a couple 6's.  If I run this 1000 times, will it approximate a normal distribution or should I expect it to stay relatively predictable?  I'm trying to understand the predictability of pseudo random number generation.

Answer (score 0):

Failure to produce specific patterns is a typical weakness of PRNGs, but the probability of hitting a substantial run of repeated digits at random is so small it's hard to demonstrate that weakness.

It's perfectly reasonable for a PRNG to use only a 32-bit state, which (traditionally) means producing a sequence of four billion numbers and then repeating from the start again.  In that case your sequence of 50 coin-flips coming out the same is *probably* never going to happen (four billion tries at something that has a one in a quadrillion chance is unlikely to succeed); but if it does, then it's going to appear *way too often*.

Superficially you're looking for k-dimensional equidistribution as a test for whether or not you can expect to find a prescribed pattern in the output without deeper analysis of the specific generator.  If your generator claims at least 50-dimensional equidistribution then you're guaranteed to see the 50-heads state at least once.

However, if your generator emits 32-bit results but you only test whether each result maps to heads or tails, you have some chance at success even if the generator fails the k-dimension test, and that chance depends on the specifics of the generator and the mapping function.

If you adjust the implementation of your generator to return just one bit at a time, then you have an opportunity to try to squeeze 50 heads out of just 50 bits of state (or potentially as few as 18, but that generator would probably be faulty).  Provided the generator visits all 2**50 possible states, one of those states will produce 50 heads in a row.  You may get a few more heads when adjacent states start or end with more zeroes.